# When does The Great Wall become obsolete?

Tags: civilization-5

Before a recent patch change, the Colossus used to go obsolete upon Navigation:

> Goes obsolete once any player researches the Navigation technology.

Pretty clear wording.

The Great Wall, however, is a little more ambiguous:

> Upon discovering Dynamite, The Great Wall becomes obsolete.

The question is, **whose discovery of Dynamite**? The owner of the wall? The enemy trying to walk inside the wall's owner's territory? Any player, like the Colossus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Great Wall will become obsolete when its owner researches Dynamite.

That seems to be the case in general as well: unless stated otherwise, the nation that built a wonder or troops has to be the one to research whatever technology obsoletes them before that happens.

Comment: Bizarre.  You'd think that if I had nukes it would make any wall you might have irrelevant.  I like Civ II better.  Get off my lawn.  Etc.

Comment: It's certainly not a new precedent. In Civ III all obsolescence is triggered by the owner's tech alone.